# Fastest way to find a re.compile match in list

Tags: python, performance, list, python-2.5

I have a text file that has 120000 lines, where every line has exactly this format:
**ean_code;plu;name;price;state**

I tried various operations, including working with file straight away, and best results were given if file was just loaded in memory line by line with readlines() and written to list (at the start of the program).

so i have these 2 lines:

```
matcher = re.compile('^(?:'+eanic.strip()+'(?:;|$)|[^;]*;'+eanic.strip()+'(?:;|$))').match
line=[next(l.split(';') for l in list if matcher(l))]
do sth with line....
```

What these lines are trying to accomplish is, they are trying to find (as fast as possible) a plu/ean, which was given by user input in fields: **ean_code or plu**.

I am particulary interested in second line, as it impacts my performance on WinCE device (PyCE port of python 2.5).

I tried every possible solution there is to make it faster, but this is fastest way to iterate through a certain list to find a match that re.compile is generating.

Any faster way other than **for** in list comprehension to iterate over big list (120000 lines in my case)?

I am looking for any kind of way possible with any kind of data structure (that is supported until Python 2.5) that will give me faster result than above two lines...

Just to mention, that this is performed on Handheld device (630MHz ARM), with 256MB RAM, and without any kind of connection besides USB is present. Sadly, database access and existance is not an option.

Comment: As long as you have to access every single element in the list, i would say no.

Comment: Just make your own string parser using the string methods instead of a regular expression, it will likely be much faster. If you show an example of your input and the output you want, I'm sure someone could help you optimize.

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way to do exactly this operation faster. Maybe you need to rethink what you need: Is there a way to reject some lines without using the regex? Can you use the regex to match the whole text at once instead of each line? Parsing 120000 lines in python will always be somewhat slow in python, independently of the complexity of the parse operation, since there's a lot of overhead

Comment: I'll clarify in the original post..

Comment: Do you even need a regexp? Looks like you could get away with something like [x for x in [split(line, ";") for line in f.readlines()] if x[0] is eanic]

Comment: why do you use `[next(...)]` construction? It finds the first match and creates a list that contains it as the only item. Is it what you've intended it to do?

Comment: @yaccz: drop `.readlines()`, don't use `is` to compare strings: `found = next(line for line in file for ean_code, plu, _,_,_ in line.split(';') if ean_code == eanic or plu == eanic)` -- find the first line that  has `eanic` in the first or second column.

Comment: Line i need is unique...thats why i am using next

Comment: @Yaccz: i don't need regex, but with it i got best times so far. I need a blazing fast solution whatever the means :)

Comment: does a regular expression, that is less complex speed the search up? `'(^|;)%s;' % panic.strip()`

Comment: No koffein, it does for a minor 1ms on quad core, biggest bottleneck here is split().

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Biggest bottleneck here is split(), here is what i tried: found = next([x] + [y] + z.split(';') for x, y, z in (line.split(';', 2) for line in imena_artikala) if x==ean1 or y==ean1), this is somewhat modified solution of yours, since it splits whole string only when it finds it. Otherwise, it splits only 2 ";". And it's still slower.

Comment: @sale1902: I find explicit loops are sometimes faster than generator expressions (make sure to put them in a function). `.split(';', 2)` is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a test file and tested a few variations. The fastest way of searching for a static string (as you appear to be doing) by iterating over the file is by using `string in line`.

However, if you'll be using the loaded data to search more than once (actually more than 30 times according to the testnumbers below), it's worth your (computational) time to produce lookup tables for the PLUs and EANs in the form of `dicts` and use these for future searches.

```
loaded 120000 lines
question regex    0.114868402481
simpler regex     0.417045307159
other regex       0.386662817001
startswith        0.236350297928
string in         0.020356798172  <-- iteration winner
dict construction 0.611148500443
dict lookup       0.000002503395  <-- best if you are doing many lookups
```

Test code follows:

```
import re
import timeit

def timefunc(function, times, *args):
    def wrap():
        function(*args)
    t = timeit.Timer(wrap)
    return t.timeit(times) / times

def question(lines):
    eanic = "D41RP9"
    matcher = re.compile('^(?:'+eanic.strip()+'(?:;|$)|[^;]*;'+eanic.strip()+'(?:;|$))').match
    line=[next(l.split(';') for l in lines if matcher(l))]
    return line

def splitstart(lines):
    eanic = "D41RP9"
    ret = []
    for l in lines:
        s = l.split(';')
        if s[0].startswith(eanic) or s[1].startswith(eanic):
            ret.append(l)
    return ret

def simpler(lines):
    eanic = "D41RP9"
    matcher = re.compile('(^|;)' + eanic)
    return [l for l in lines if matcher.search(l)]

def better(lines):
    eanic = "D41RP9"
    matcher = re.compile('^(?:' + eanic + '|[^;]*;' + eanic + ')')
    return [l for l in lines if matcher.match(l)]

def strin(lines):
    eanic = "D41RP9"
    return [l for l in lines if eanic in l]

def mkdicts(lines):
    ean = {}
    plu = {}
    for l in lines:
        s = l.split(';')
        ean[s[0]] = s
        plu[s[1]] = s
    return (ean, plu)

def searchdicts(ean, plu):
    eanic = "D41RP9"
    return (ean.get(eanic, None), plu.get(eanic, None))

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    print "loaded", len(lines), "lines"
    print "question regex\t", timefunc(question, 10, lines)
    print "simpler regex\t", timefunc(simpler, 10, lines)
    print "other regex\t", timefunc(simpler, 10, lines)
    print "startswith\t", timefunc(splitstart, 10, lines)
    print "string in\t", timefunc(strin, 10, lines)
    print "dict construction\t", timefunc(mkdicts, 10, lines)
    ean, plu = mkdicts(lines)
    print "dict lookup\t", timefunc(searchdicts, 10, ean, plu)
```

Comment: +1 for measuring the thing. How long does `f.readlines()` take compared to the timed functions? Do you test that all functions produce the same result?

Comment: There are parts which will contain other parts values e.g. 23 will be contained in 323 for PLU in another line. Therefore: found=[l for l in imena_artikala if ";"+ean1+";" in l or ean1+";"==l[0:len(ean1)+1]] is the closest solution to yours (using in) that i could've come to. Still slower.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian No, they produce slightly different results, but probably not enough to make any difference.

Comment: @sale1902 Are you going to be searching multiple times on the same data? Also, consider that `string in` is about 5 times faster; you can get some false positives and filter them out after you've split the result strings.

Comment: OH...MY...god..2ms to find a value in last line, that means 120000th line. Compared to 40ms that i was getting before...seriously...i will never use list again. Dict ftw!!!! Gotta test it just abit further, but 100 thumbs up!

Comment: @sale1902 prepare the string,  you use with `in` before you use it. `";"+ean1+";"`  will be added every time. Besides you shouldn't add strings: `";%s;" % ean1`.
Also use `l.startswith(ean1)` instead of `ean1+";"==l[0:len(ean1)+1]`

Answer (score 0):

At first I looked up some modules, that are available for python 2.5:

You can use [csv-module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-csv.html) to read your data. Could be faster.

You can store your data via [pickle or cPickle module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-pickle.html). So you can store python-objects (like dict, tuples, ints and so on). Comparing ints is faster than searching in strings.

You iterate through a list, but you say your data are in a text file. Do not load your whole text file in a list. Maybe the following is fast enough and there is no need for using the modules I mentioned above.

```
f = open('source.txt','r') # note: python 2.5, no with-statement yet
stripped_eanic = eanic.strip()
for line in f:
    if stripped_eanic in line: # the IDs have a maximum length, don't they? So maybe just search in line[:20]
        # run further tests, if you think it is necessary
        if further_tests:
            print line
            break
else:
    print "No match"
```

**Edit**

I thought about what I mentioned above: Do not load the whole file in a list. I think that is only true, if your search is a onetime procedure and your script exits there. But if you want to search several times I suggest using `dict` (like beerbajay suggested) and `cPickle`-files instead of text-file.